# How to use polars.concat_str to combine multiple columns selected by regex?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a problem to merge columns into one. Say I have a dataframe (df) like below:

```
>> print(df)

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b_a_1 ┆ b_a_2 ┆ b_a_3 │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ a--   ┆       ┆       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆       ┆ b--   ┆       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆       ┆       ┆ c--   │
└─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

And I want to be able to merge the last three (3) columsn into one using python-polars. I have tried and successfully got what I want. However,

```
>> out = df.select(pl.concat_str(['b_a_1', 'b_a_2', 'b_a_3']).alias('b_a'))
>> print(out)

shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ b_a │
│ --- │
│ str │
╞═════╡
│ a-- │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b-- │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c-- │
└─────┘
```

when I use regex in selecting the columns, I don't get the above result

```
>> out = df.select(pl.concat_str('^b_a_\d$'))
>> print(out)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ b_a_1 ┆ b_a_2 ┆ b_a_3 │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ a--   ┆       ┆       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│       ┆ b--   ┆       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│       ┆       ┆ c--   │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

and nothing when run

```
>> out = df.select(pl.concat_str('^b_a_*$'))
>> print(out)

shape: (0, 0)
┌┐
╞╡
└┘
```

How am I to select the columns with regex and combine them into one?

Thank you very much for your time and suggestion.

Sincerely,
Thi An

Comment: We need to adapt `concat_str` so that it expands the regex to an input. I will do that in next release.

Comment: A workaround solution I was doing for this issue is to first get the pattern compiled `import re; patt = re.compile('^b_a_*');` and then get all columns that match that pattern by `cols = [c for c in df.columns if patt.search(c)]`. Finally, used all `cols` in `pl.concat_str(cols)`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the [current behavior](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.concat_str.html#polars-concat-str) of `polars.concat_str` when joining str with a null is to output a null, a possible workaround is to use `.fill_null`, replacing Nulls by empty strings on the relevant columns.

```
(
df.select([
    pl.concat_str(
        pl.col("^b_a_\d$").fill_null("").alias("b_a")
        )
    ])
)

shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ b_a │
│ --- │
│ str │
╞═════╡
│ a-- │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b-- │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c-- │
└─────┘
```